# How to fix code python face recognition check for unregistered faces to show Unknown

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition, knn

Please Help me. I'm running a face recognition detector python program that will display the data from pickle file and i wrote a code displaying the unknown faces as unknown...

This code is a program for identifying faces using K-Nearest Neighbors (KNN).
How to fix code python face recognition check for unregistered faces to show Unknown.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import cv2
import pickle
import numpy as np
import os
import csv
import time
from datetime import datetime


video=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
facedetect=cv2.CascadeClassifier('data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

with open('data/names.pkl', 'rb') as w:
    LABELS=pickle.load(w)
with open('data/faces_data.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    FACES=pickle.load(f)

print('Shape of Faces matrix --> ', FACES.shape)

knn=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
knn.fit(FACES, LABELS)

imgBackground=None

COL_NAMES = ['NAME', 'TIME']

while True:
    ret,frame=video.read()
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces=facedetect.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3 ,5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        crop_img=frame[y:y+h, x:x+w, :]
        resized_img=cv2.resize(crop_img, (50,50)).flatten().reshape(1,-1)
        output=knn.predict(resized_img)
        ts=time.time()
        date=datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
        timestamp=datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        exist=os.path.isfile("Attendance/Attendance_" + date + ".csv")
        recognized_name = "unknown" 
        if len(LABELS) >= 0:
                recognized_name = output[0]


        attendance = [recognized_name, str(timestamp)]
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,0,255), 1)
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(50,50,255),2)
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y-40),(x+w,y),(50,50,255),-1)
        cv2.putText(frame, str(output[0]), (x,y-15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (255,255,255), 1)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (50,50,255), 1)
        
    if imgBackground is not None and not imgBackground.empty():
        imgBackground[162:162 + frame.shape[0], 55:55 + frame.shape[1]] = frame
        cv2.imshow("Frame", imgBackground)
    else:
        cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

    k=cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k==ord('o'):
        if exist:
            with open("Attendance/Attendance_" + date + ".csv", "+a") as csvfile:
                writer=csv.writer(csvfile)
                writer.writerow(attendance)
            csvfile.close()
        else:
            with open("Attendance/Attendance_" + date + ".csv", "+a") as csvfile:
                writer=csv.writer(csvfile)
                writer.writerow(COL_NAMES)
                writer.writerow(attendance)
            csvfile.close()
    if k==ord('q'):
        break
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I want it to show unknown faces when catching people who are not registered.

Please..

Thank for Help ....

Comment: Please provide more information on what the actual problem is. Does your code produce an error or are the results just not what you expect?

Comment: I didn't get the results I had hoped for. when running the program And the program to check the faces of people who have not trained their faces is famous for people who have trained their faces.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.